# Extending Automorphisms, Isomorphisms

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

Suppose we have an isomorphism $\varphi: K_1 \to K_2$ where there is a base field $F$ and a  Galois extension field $L$, ie, $F \subsetneq K_1, K_2 \subsetneq L$, $\varphi|_F = Id$ and $|Gal(L/F)| < \infty$. One case we consider is that where $K_1 = K_2$ and thus $\varphi$ is an automorphism of $K_1$ fixing $F$. Does there exist an automorphism $\overline{\varphi} \in Gal(L/F)$ such that $\overline{\varphi}|_{K_1} = \varphi$?

I propose the following proof that such an automorphism exists, though I am not certain as to its validity.

Suppose $\varphi:K_1 \to K_2$ as above. Since $L$ is Galois over $K_1$ we have by the Primitive Element Theorem that $L = K_1(\alpha)$. Thus, $1, \alpha, ... , \alpha^{n-1}$ is a basis for $L$ over $K_1$. Let $m_{\alpha, K_1} \in K_1[x]$ denote the minimal polynomial of $\alpha \in L$ over $K_1$. Let $\beta$ be a root of $\varphi(m_{\alpha, K_1})$ where we extend $\varphi$ naturally to a ring homomorphism from $K_1[x]$ to $K_2[x]$. Then since $K_1 \cong K_2$, $K_1(\alpha) \cong K_2(\beta)$. Since $L = K_1(\alpha) \cong K_2(\beta)$, I claim there exists $\beta \in L$ such that $\varphi(m_{\alpha, K_1})(\beta) = 0$. Thus, $1, \beta, ... , \beta^{n-1}$ is a basis for $L$ over $K_2$ and if we let $\overline{\varphi} |_{K_1} = \varphi$ and $\overline{\varphi}: \alpha \mapsto \beta$, then $\overline{\varphi}$ is the desired automorphism of $L$.

I believe the weakest claim is that $\beta \in K_1(\alpha) = L$, and I am not sure how to shore it up. I would love feedback on the rest of the proof as well.

Comment: In the second line of the first paragraph, what do you mean by $K$? Do you mean $K=K_1=K_2$? Also, what is $m_{\alpha,K_1}$?

Comment: @user30535 Yeah, I meant $K=K_1=K_2$, was a bit lazy. $m_{\alpha, K_1} \in K_1[x]$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K_1$ (It's the notation used by our book, Dummit and Foote). Will edit in now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the crucial point of your proof is the following.

$m_{\alpha,K_{1}}$ divides $m_{\alpha,F}$.

Now

- $L/F$ is Galois,
- $m_{\alpha,F}$ is irreducible in $F[x]$, and
- $m_{\alpha,F}$ has a root $\alpha$ in $L$.

This yields that $m_{\alpha,F}$ splits completely in $L$.

Now $\varphi(m_{\alpha, K_1})$ also divides $m_{\alpha,F}$, as $\varphi$ fixes $F$ pointwise, so $\varphi(m_{\alpha, K_1})$ also splits completely in $L$, and there's your $\beta$.

Comment: Thanks! It felt right that $\beta$ would be there.

Answer (score 0):

I think your proof works fine (provided you can show that $\beta$ exists). Here is an alternative:

Since you are using Dummit and Foote, take a look at theorem 27 on page 541 (of the 3rd edition). Since $L/F$ is a finite Galois extension, then it is the splitting field of some $f\in F[x]$, then $L/K_1$ and $L/K_2$ are splitting fields for $f\in K_1[x]$ and $f\in K_2[x]$ respectively. Then applying the theorem gives exactly the extended automorphism you are looking for.

Comment: Ah! We hadn't thought to use the splitting field isomorphism. That's a sweet solution. This sort of circumvents the whole minimal polynomial thing, right?

Comment: @so63 I don't think it circumvents the minimal polynomial argument, it just hides it in the proof of the theorem. You should read the proof, you will probably have to use a minimal polynomial argument that is similar to your original argument.